# Resizing window terminator with hotkeys?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, terminator

I want to resize the window of terminator with a hotkey or with a command on the commandline.

It would be great if I could make several hotkeys/commands for different sizes of windows.

Example: term 80 (turning the window into 80 columns and 23 rows) or F5 (doing the same thing).

I have a 1280 by 1024 resolution.